# How to alter the password for www-data user?

Tags: password

Apache was installed, `www-data` is owner of `/var/www/html/wp`.
I miss the key, and want to alter it now.

```
sudo cat /etc/shadow |grep www-data
www-data:*:17053:0:99999:7:::
```

To change it into `www-data::17053:0:99999:7:::` and save it.

```
su www-data
Password:
```

To input enter, no character inputed.

```
su: Authentication failure
```

How to alter the password for `www-data` user?

Comment: Why don't you add yourself to the `www-data` group instead so your can inherit all its permissions hope you know what your doing messing with `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Answer (score 8):

To change another user's password, use:

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

So:

```
sudo passwd www-data
```

Though I don't see why `www-data` should have a password.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo` privileges to `su` to the user `www-data`

```
sudo su www-data
```

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for the correction!i also didn't see his statement of "i miss the key"

Comment: You can still perform operations as `www-data` with `sudo -u www-data COMMAND...` even if the account is disabled (assuming your account has `sudo` privileges).